# search folder and all sub folders for a specific file type

Tags: vb.net, search

I used below code to store all .txt files in a specific path in an array.

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderDIR, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

folderDIR is the directory of the folder i want to search in. But this method doesnt seem to work. It takes all the .txt files in current location, but does not consider the subfolders.

Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: are you certain "folderDir" has sub folders and those folders have .TXT files in them?

Comment: now, i have found the issue. above code is perfect. Problem was with my Directory. Thanks @Plutonix. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: try this : `Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderDIR, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

```
' For Directory.GetFiles and Directory.GetDirectories 
' For File.Exists, Directory.Exists  
    Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class RecursiveFileProcessor

    Public Overloads Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim path As String 
        For Each path In args
            If File.Exists(path) Then 
                ' This path is a file.
                ProcessFile(path)
            Else 
                If Directory.Exists(path) Then 
                    ' This path is a directory.
                    ProcessDirectory(path)
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path)
                End If 
            End If 
        Next path
    End Sub 'Main


    ' Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories  
    ' that are found, and process the files they contain. 
    Public Shared Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
        Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
        ' Process the list of files found in the directory. 
        Dim fileName As String 
        For Each fileName In fileEntries
            ProcessFile(fileName)

        Next fileName
        Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
        ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
        Dim subdirectory As String 
        For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
        Next subdirectory

    End Sub 'ProcessDirectory

    ' Insert logic for processing found files here. 
    Public Shared Sub ProcessFile(ByVal path As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path)
    End Sub 'ProcessFile
End Class 'RecursiveFileProcessor
```